# Elasticsearch type and attribute name inference

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with Elasticsearch 1.7 and ran into following Problem:
When an Attribute is named as a type of the index i cant filter on the attribute without involving the type name. I better show you an example:

Indexing:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/myindex/ingredient/1" -d'
{
  "name": "salad"
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/myindex/product/1" -d'
{
  "name": "sandwich",
  "ingredient": {
    "name": "salad"
  }
}'
```

Filtering:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "ingredient.name": "salad"
    }
  }
}'
```

Response:

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "ingredient",
  "_id": "1",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "name": "salad"
  }
}
```

The Problem:
The response is of type ingredient. I wanted to  get objects that have attribute ingredient.name="salad". Elasticsearch understands the attribute name as a type. When I filter on product.ingredient.name="salad", i get the product as expected.

I cannot get the type of the thing i want to filter on, is there another way to say, that i mean the attribute name, not a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in elasticsearch:1.x wherein there are multiple ways to refer to the one field leading to ambiguity.

There is no better way around it other than

a) explicitly  prepending  the `type`  as mentioned in the OP

b)  restricting the search to a specific `type`
`http://localhost:9200/myindex/<type>/_search`

This is fixed in elasticsearch 2.x. This [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring#ambiguous-fields) from elastica has a good explanation with regard to this.

Comment: Thanks, for clearing that out. I think, i have to update then.